# rds unable to grant role to a user using root user

Tags: mysql, terraform, amazon-rds

I have a mysql rds instance, when you make the instance you declare a root user and a password.

I am then using terraform to create a new user and give the user a role. However i get the following error:

```
 Error running SQL (GRANT 'test_role' TO 'test_user'@'%'): Error 1227: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the WITH ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN, SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Putting terraform aside, if i attempt to assign a role to a user with mysql directly. I get the same error

```
CREATE ROLE 'test_role';
GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON checkpoint_gg.* TO 'test_role';
CREATE USER 'test_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT 'test_role' TO 'test_user'@'%';
```

**SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';**

```
'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `root`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION'
'GRANT APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,FLUSH_OPTIMIZER_COSTS,FLUSH_STATUS,FLUSH_TABLES,FLUSH_USER_RESOURCES,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ARCHIVE,PASSWORDLESS_USER_ADMIN,SHOW_ROUTINE ON *.* TO `root`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION'
```

mysql 8

Comment: Looks like this is a similar unanswered issue from 2019 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442801/grant-role-to-user-denied-with-error-code-1227-in-mysql-8-0-aws

Comment: I have successfully granted permissions to new MySQL users with the RDS admin user set upon RDS Instance Creation with a MySQL Client (not using terraform resource mysql_grant). I wonder if terraform is trying to run mysql_grant before the admin user is actually ready to use. Can you manually create new users and roles with your RDS Admin user after the RDS instance is ready?
Possibly adding terraform meta-argument `depends_on = [mysql_role.checkpoint_developer]` in resource block `mysql_role.checkpoint_developer` could help & adding `depends_on` in the other resource blocks accordingly.

Comment: Using mysql workbench i tried to manually grant the role to user and got the same erorr. So i dont believe that is the case (event the terraform logs show that the user has been created). Im not entirely sure wht you mean by granted permissions, i am trying to assign a role to a user. I can apply a mysql_grant to a user but not a mysql_role.

Comment: You can check the update on my question, even running the raw sql, the last step `GRANT 'test_role' TO 'test_user'@'%';` fails with the same error @paulg

Comment: I've removed the terraform config and reduced the content of the question to set the bounty

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted aws technical support and they managed to replicate the issue and suggest a solution.

**aws technical support**

> since RDS is a managed service, to maintain the system integrity and
> stability, super user privileges are not provided even to the master
> user of the DB instance, and therefore, such error message is
> expected, as the RDS MySQL master user by default does not have the
> ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN, SUPER privileges.

They suggested, interestingly enough the master/root user can assign those roles to itself.

```
GRANT ROLE_ADMIN on *.* to root;
```

Once it has that privilege we can then grant a role to a user

```
GRANT 'test_role' TO 'test_user'@'%';
```

I did not know the master root user (not rdsadmin) could give it self admin role, when itself is not an admin or does not have super privileges.

Comment: so how are we suppose to manage the database without a super admin account? Super user we create has only the USAGE privillages ?

Comment: Legend! This has worked a charm

Answer (score -3):

1. Please try to create rds cluster with master username other than root, it can be reserved username.
2. As mentioned in the error, your user does not have ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN or SUPER permissions. Grant one of this permission.
   Also make sure that you actually use @'%' user, not @'localhost'

Comment: Hey, chill, just trying to help ya.
If you dont have variable to set username, it does  not mean tf module not has it behind the scene.

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.0.34/reference/rds/create-db-cluster.html

``` lang-yaml
[--master-username <value>]
[--master-user-password <value>]
```


https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance

``` lang-yaml
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "foobarbaz"
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/reserved-accounts.html
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52278/not-able-to-login-on-mysql-in-aws-rds-using-root

Comment: None of what you've mentioned has been helpful.